# How to call the jenkins job URL in meteor server side?

Tags: node.js, http, url, meteor, jenkins

My requirement:

1. Get the URL of jenkins job.
2. Make an HTTP.call(method,URL,options)

I have written some Meteor server code:

```
var URL = "123.11.22.33:8080/view/test/job/create_job/buildWithParameters?INSTANCE_NAME="+name;
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http'
var deleteparams = HTTP.call('POST',URL, { auth:"root:root"});
```

but when I try to execute this code I get the error like below and not will not proceed further.

**Error message:**

```
Exception while invoking method 'sendHttp' Error: failed [403]          <!DOCTYPE html><html><head resURL="/static/9ea3e32c" data-rooturl="" data-resurl="/static/9ea3e32c">           <title>Jenkins</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/9ea3e32c/css/layout-common.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/9ea3e32c/css/style.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/9ea3e32c/css/color.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/9ea3e32c/css/responsive-grid.css" type="text/css" /><link rel="shortcut icon...
    at Object.Future.wait (/opt/test/pack1.f/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:449:15)
    at Object.call (packages/meteor.js:213:24)
    at [object Object].Meteor.methods.sendHttp (Server/methods.js:711:34)
    at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1711:12)
    at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:711:19
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1122:17)
    at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:709:40
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1122:17)
    at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:707:46
    at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.method (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:681:23)
    - - - - -
    at makeErrorByStatus (packages/http/httpcall_common.js:13:10)
    at Request._callback (packages/http/httpcall_server.js:113:17)
    at Request.self.callback (/opt/test/pack1.f/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/http/node_modules/request/request.js:200:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/opt/test/pack1.f/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/http/node_modules/request/request.js:1067:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/opt/test/pack1.f/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/http/node_modules/request/request.js:988:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this?

Comment: HTTP error 403  means that the access to that page is forbidden. Does jenkins have any mechanism to allow / deny external http connections?

Comment: Nope, there are no mechanisum in jenkins to block the external http calls. Only username and password is required.

Comment: Can you simply pass the authentication in the url itself? Like ```url = 'http://user:pass@localhost:8080'```

Comment: thank you..Everytime the request timeout happening, form page was not loading. It was due to change of server.